# What's the difference between slow-query-log vs long_query_time

Tags: mysql

What's the difference between slow queries and long queries?

By following some tutorials, I have my settings set to:

```
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysqld-slow-query.log
long_query_time = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

However, it's still logging queries under 1 second long.

Comment: yea finally some questions and answers for upvotes

Comment: oh, I liked the Q and A's and upvoted them

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `slow-query-log = 1` enables the slow query log, it logs the SQL statements that took more than `long_query_time` seconds to execute.

`log-queries-not-using-indexes` tells MySQL to log *any* queries that do not use indexes regardless of the setting in `long_query_time`.

More details can be found in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: So why would this is logged `# Query_time: 0.296053  Lock_time: 0.000025 Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 896829` since it's less than 1 second?

Comment: Almost certainly those queries aren't using indexes and therefore are affected by `log-queries-not-using-indexes`.